# How to force screen to scroll down upon clicking text field?

Tags: flutter

I have this code and when i click on textfield it DOES appear on middle of screen above the keyboard, but it's very tightly fit there and the text below it does not appear. How can i make it so that when I click on the textfield the scrolling is enough to show the text below it as well?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 600,),
              TextField(
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              Text("I want this text to appear ")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of use sizebox to force size you could use expanded with flex so when the screen does the resize it will do it in the new screen height look how it workin here https://youtu.be/_rnZaagadyo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

There is no exact solution for this, however you can use `ScrollController` to scroll the rest of the area in your `SingleChildScrollView`

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 600),
          TextField(
            onTap: () {
              Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Text("I want this text to appear "),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}.
```

Comment: That looks fairly neat, how customizable is this though, like for example say I want this to scroll a specific amount of pixels, or % of the screen or so. Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: It's fully customizable, you can do it as you need.